# Qt window layout spans beyond window borders when QOpenGLWidget is present

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

There is a Qt window, which hosts many widgets, among them is one `QOpenGLWidget` widget to plot waveform. This works well on almost all machines, but there is one strange case with a machine having an `Intel OpenGL graphics version 3.3.0 - Build 21.20.164678`.

This is the good behavior on almost all machines:

[image: The good behavior]

And this is the strange case, wherein title text goes beyond top border of the window, and to click a button, we have to offset mouse pointer above the rendered position of that button. Text is also a little bit blurry. This problem does not happen if I replace the OpenGL widget with another non-OpenGL widget:

[image]

Any suggestions to fix the issue?

Comment: Hi, Can you share the code sample for this one?
What layout are you using to achieve this?

Comment: @Dinesh Hi, Here is the UI code. The `glframe` there is the QOpenGLWidget container: https://gist.github.com/alitavakol/e11c7744aa688f803fed96b9ccf5955f

Comment: Have you implemented the correct sizeHint()/minimumSizeHint() methods in your QOpenGLWidget class? Since it is a custom widget, and Qt doesn't know what it's preferred size is for the layout calculation and you need to provide size hints.

Here's a quick link on how to do that. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#custom-widgets-in-layouts.

Alternatively, you can set the sizePolicy() of your `glframe` to `Fixed`, `Fixed` and set a fixed size to the widget.